# directly use MemmapingPool in python joblib module

Tags: python, multiprocessing, joblib

the `joblib` module has provided a tremendously easy-to-use function `Parallel` to simplify coding. However, it always gathers all the results before you can access any of them.

I have the need to deal with the results one by one because the results are big arrays taking a lot of memory. They cannot reside in the memory at the same time. So I need to deal with part of them first and then discard. Originally, I used `futures.as_completed` method from `MultiprocessPool` so that results can be handled immediately when they are available.

But now I also want to use `joblib` to manage the `memmap`ed arrays for me. Does `joblib` also has the interface like `MultiprocessPool`? I looked into the code a little and found `MemmapingPool`. But these is no document and examples on how to use it.

I have the following questions:

1. Do I use them the same as using `MultiprocessPool`?
2. How to handle `Ctrl-C` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and reading the source code of joblib, I get a way to do so by manually manage the memmapped arrays. A code snippet has been posted to [gist](https://gist.github.com/liushapku/ca47de750197f42290e58ad92c46c7e2#file-gistfile1-txt).

The simplest way to use it is through the `wrap` function, which will automatically detect `memmap` and wrap it in SharedArray. The return value will also be wrapped in SharedArray if it is a memmap. Example:

```
x = np.memmap('data', dtype=int, mode='w+', shape=100)
x[:] = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(2) as pool:
    fut1 = pool.submit(*wrap(np.multiply, x[:50], 2))
    fut2 = pool.submit(*wrap(np.multiply, x[50:], -2))
    print(fut1.result())  # or fut1.result().asarray() in case the function returns a memmap
    print(fut2.result())
```